# Error getting on creating project on phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am new to Phonegap. I have download cordova-2.4.0 and going to create new project through terminal. But i am getting following error.

i am run following command

```
./create ~/Documents/Cordova22/HelloWorld org.apache.cordova.HelloWorld HelloWorld
```

i am getting following Errors

```
cat: some/path : No such file or directory
cat: some/path : No such file or directory
cat: Cordova/cordova-2.4.0/cordova-ios/bin/../CordovaLib/VERSION: No such file or directory
```

Plz help. Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put cordova-2.4.0 Library (whole directory) in same directory where you make your project directory. Suppose my project destination is "Documents/Cordova22/" then put cordova-2.4.0 Library in same directory.

Your Library path should be like this

```
"Documents/Cordova22/cordova-2.4.0"
```

And your project path should be like this

```
"Documents/Cordova22/HelloWorld"
```

Answer (score 1):

I forget to put cordova-2.4.0 Library (whole directory) in "Documents/Cordova22/".